# Is there a way to get a non-linear (weighted) gradient with imagemagick?

Tags: gradient, imagemagick

Looking at [creating gradients with imagemagick](https://imagemagick.org/script/gradient.php) (or here [using sparse-color](https://legacy.imagemagick.org/Usage/canvas/#sparse_summery)) I can only see how to make a linear gradient between points. But how could I make a non-linear gradient? Like, how to I assign more weight to one of the points in the gradient? For example I'm using this line to assign some diagonal transparency to an image:

```
convert in.png -alpha set -background none -channel A \
-sparse-color barycentric "0,%[h] none -%w,0 none %w,0 white" +channel out.png
```

But I'd like more transparency. I'd like the gradient to be more weighted towards the transparent points. Quadratic gradient? Maybe something like this [shepard's power](https://legacy.imagemagick.org/Usage/canvas/#shepards_power) method, but if I could assign different powers to each point? Can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to work with this is to compose the transparency gradient as a greyscale and the use `copy-opacity` to shunt that into the alpha channel. In your example, the image itself would be all white with a gradient alpha.

You can do functions and math with imagemagick, so something like `gradient: -function Polynomial -4,4,0 -evaluate Pow 0.9` would be be black-white-black. The 4-point gradient examples in your cite also would work if conceived as a greyscale and set for the alpha.

Helpful resource (far too in depth to properly quote): http://im.snibgo.com/gradients.htm